# What is the industry term for superset of "metrics" and "dimensions"?

Tags: database-design, terminology, application-design, dimensional-modeling

If I want to refer to *measures*/*metrics* and *dimensions* with a single term, what would be a good industry-accepted expression?

*Metrics* is used commonly in UIs as well such as [Google Analytics](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033861?hl=en) or [Tableau](http://tableau.com/drive/dimensions-and-measures-intro).

The context for my question is for a UI. I'd like to group both of them and refer to them with an industry-accepted name, if one exists.

Comment: Welcome to the site BTW. I edited the details from your comments in the question. Feel free to roll back my edits or edit the question yourself if I got it wrong or if you want to add more details yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Dimensions and Measures are the two main components of cubes. The dimensions are basically ways *to look at the data* while the measures *are the data*.

When writing MDX the measures are a member of the `[Measures]` dimension but that is mostly a syntax convention.

As for a common name, I would say they both are partly definitions of a cube design. The measures define the values and the dimensions define how you slice or aggregate the measures.

The combined result of a query across dimension members and measures is called a [cellset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/multidimensional/working-with-multidimensional-data?view=sql-server-2017) but that term is used for a result rather than a cube definition (which is what measures and dimensions are).

If there even is a common term for the combination of dimensions and measures it would be [physical aspects of data aggregation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/what-are-measures-and-dimensions)

If I were to design a UI where I list both in an interface for users to add a report I would probably call them 'report items' or 'data components'  or something but I think the clearest for an end user would be to follow  what Excel does and label them 'rows' or 'columns' and 'values' where things you can add to rows/columns are the dimensions and values are the measures.

I don't think it's any clearer to an end user to try and find a common name and from a UI design perspective I would make a distinction between things they should put on an axis and 'values'.

Answer (score -1):

I would call the screen "Measuring" and there you can define your "Dimensions", like X, Y, Z, time and then use the dimensions to perform "Measures" (is that a word?) or "Measurements" like 5 meters, 20 seconds.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. Measures is a known term in multidimensional databases. I'm not sure your answer is addressing the question. Maybe you could expand on it by adding more explanation?

Comment: It's possible that your explanation will help the OP to understand better what each of those is but the question wasn't about this. The OP is looking for a single umbrella term for both measures and dimensions ("I want to refer to measures/metrics and dimensions with a single term").

Comment: Andriy M is exactly correct. Surprisingly, there doesn't seem to be a commonly agreed-upon term for this?